# React warning when using ReferenceInput with RadioButtonGroupInput

Tags: react-admin

When using the RadioButtonGroupInput inside ReferenceInput I get some warnings from React:
React does not recognize the `setFilter` prop on a DOM element
React does not recognize the `setPagination` prop on a DOM element
etc...
It seems the RadioButtonGroup does not support this props, is this a bug?

Here is an example, it only appears the first time we click an item of a list. After we need to reload to see it again

https://codesandbox.io/s/6j878j2263